# How to save array to csv file without converting it to a string?

Tags: python, csv

I have an array that looks like this:

```
data_struct = [[0,'YES',0.25,[[[234], [432], ..., [523]]]], 
               [0,'YES',0.25,[[[234], [432], ..., [523]]]]]
```

I want to save to it to a csv file so that I can use the data as is for later.

I am currently trying this:

```
with open(r'data.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data_struct[0])
```

Which works fine, but the problem is that the fourth element in each row ( the large arrays) turn into a string so it becomes :

```
"[[[234],\n[432],\n ..., [523]]]]"
```

I want to load the csv file later and have the data in the same format.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: How show the fourth array in each row be stored in the csv file?

Comment: @Heike I'm sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: The first code snippet would fail with an IndexError when evaluating e. g. `[234] [432]`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yeah sorry about that, edited the commas in.

Comment: @martineau I want it to look like this: 0 , YES, 0.25, [[[234] [432]  ... [523]]]

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.savetxt. Reference:- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray(data_struct)
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Currently trying this and gave me this error: "TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')"

Comment: try numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')

Comment: Works great but I have another problem now. when I try to read the data from the csv file again it becomes: [[0 'YES' 0.25 '[[[234]' ' [432]' ' [523]]]']] instead of [[0 'YES' 0.25 [[[234], [432], [523]]]]]. I am guessing because the data is comma separated. How do I load the data as Is?

Comment: from numpy import genfromtxt

a= genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')

Comment: This is the output  from using this: [[0.    nan 0.25  nan  nan  nan]
 [0.    nan 0.25  nan  nan  nan]].

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It appends every array as a new line in your csv file and when it reads it, it returns an array of your appended arrays.

```
def appender(file, data):
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        f.write("{}\n".format(str(data)))


def loader(file):
    structs = []
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            exec("structs.append({})".format(line[:-1]))
    return structs


data_struct = [[0, 'YES', 0.25, [[[234], [432], [523]]]],
               [0, 'YES', 0.25, [[[234], [432], [523]]]]]

for i in range(5):
    appender("data.csv", data_struct)

read_data = loader("data.csv")
```

Though I do not see the point of writing your data to .csv file. Changing your arrays to dictionaries and writing a .json file would make much more sense.

Comment: Thank you this works!
I am new to python so I am just trying this out.I will also look into the other solution you suggested.

Comment: I am glad to hear that I helped